# Unable to archive build with Share Extension and AFNetworking Cocoapod

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods, ios-app-extension

I've got a share extension set up for my app and I'm using AFNetworking through a cocoapods install.
I was able to build and run the app through simulator and my phone via debug builds but when I tried to archive to submit to the app store I ran into a warning:

> linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions
>   AFNetworking

Archive builds would complete but they would be corrupted and unusable.

My solution is to stop using cocoapods for my app extension and manually add the AFNetworking files to my Compile Resources build setting.

I'm just wondering if others have had this issue OR if they have had no problems using AFNetworking cocoapod to submit an extension to the store.

I have checked out the [Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) and was using arm64 architecture and had set the target’s “Require Only App-Extension-Safe API” build setting to Yes.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know the latest version of cocoapods should set automatically "**Allow app extension API only**" flags to all libs targets if pods library is properly linked to extension target(s) (check targets from Pods.xcodeproj). If it doesn't happen you can try to set it manually in post_install hook. You can try this one:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this just for the extension target? My app itself needs to reference UIApplication…

Comment: undefined method `project' for #<Pod::Installer:0x00007fca9c3a0d40>